# call xtail by tornado.proces.Subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, tornado

How can I call `xtail` by `tornado.proces.Subprocess`?

```
import subprocess

from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado import gen
from tornado import process

class Reader(object):
    def __init__(self, xwatch_path, max_idle=600, ioloop=None):
        self.xwatch_path = xwatch_path
        self.ioloop = ioloop
        self.max_idle = max_idle

    @gen.coroutine
    def call_subprocess(self, cmd, stdin_data=None, stdin_async=False):
        stdin = STREAM if stdin_async else subprocess.PIPE
        sub_process = process.Subprocess(
            cmd, stdin=stdin, stdout=STREAM, stderr=STREAM, io_loop=self.ioloop
        )

        if stdin_data:
            if stdin_async:
                yield gen.Task(sub_process.stdin.write, stdin_data)
            else:
                sub_process.stdin.write(stdin_data)
        if stdin_async or stdin_data:
            sub_process.stdin.close()
        result, error = yield [
            gen.Task(sub_process.stdout.read_until, '\n'),
            gen.Task(sub_process.stderr.read_until, '\n')
        ]
        print result
        raise gen.Return((result, error))

    @gen.coroutine
    def popen(self):
        while True:
            result, error = yield self.call_subprocess(['xtail', self.xwatch_path])

            print result, error

def read_log(ioloop):
    access_reader = AccessLogReader(
        '/home/vagrant/logs')


    ioloop.add_callback(access_reader.popen)


def main():
    ioloop = IOLoop.instance()
    read_log(ioloop)
    ioloop.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I would like to collect a few of the log changes in the log folder, ready to use xtail multiple folders to collect logs, and then I develop the environment for debugging.

I use Vim to modify the `~/log/123.txt` file, but I can't see the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

```
result, error = yield [
    gen.Task(sub_process.stdout.read_until, '\n'),
    gen.Task(sub_process.stderr.read_until, '\n')
]
```

reads one line of the process's standard output and one line of standard error, and blocks until it has read both lines. If `xtail` only writes to one of the two streams, this will never complete.

You probably want to read in a loop (note that `gen.Task` is not necessary):

```
@gen.coroutine
def read_from_stream(stream):
    try:
        while True:
            line = yield stream.read_until('\n')
            print(line)
    except StreamClosedError:
        return
```

If you care about the difference between stdout and stderr, read from them separately. This will print lines from each stream as they arrive, and stop when both streams are closed:

```
yield [read_from_stream(sub_process.stdout), read_from_stream(sub_process.stderr)]
```

If you don't, merge them by passing `stdout=STREAM, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` when creating the subprocess, and only read from sub_process.stdout.